# How to disable option in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have `ng-repeat` option:

```
<option ng-repeat="year in data.dateList.year" value="{{year.id}}" ng-disabled="(year.id < 2015) ?  true : false">
```

You can see `ng-disabled="(year.id < 2015) ?  true : false"`

Why my option is not disabled if `year.id` less than 2015?

This is my new code:

```
<div class="itm" ng-repeat="a in range(num) track by $index">
   <option ng-repeat="year in data.dateList.year" ng-disabled="(year.id) < formData.beginYear[$index]">
      {{year.value}}
   </option>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably put the `disable` clause in your `ng-repeat` like [the example at the bottom of the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: apply filter and don't show the options only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use ng-options here which has way to disable the options

```
<select ng-model="year"
  ng-options="year.id disable when (year.id < 2015) for year in data.dateList.year">
</select>
```

**Update**

For two input field depends each other, you can do it like below. Main problem was while you were doing comparison it was string, as `value` attributes convert the value to `string` format. You could use `ng-options` that does preserves the `dataType` of the value & will make more easier while making comparison.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="yr[$index]" 
   ng-options="year.id as year.id for year in years">
</select>

<select ng-model="year" 
   ng-options="year.id disable when (year.id < yr[$index]) for year in years">
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/beHJ3zdQrYfyRoRMWR0M?p=preview)

Comment: upvoted :) and seems like his attempt is working fine though http://plnkr.co/edit/iW8l2zV9DrTXAKTYYDo6?p=preview

Comment: For me does not work for `year in data.dateList.year`

Comment: For `ng-option` it is possible?

Comment: @Ahmed could you modify this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/iW8l2zV9DrTXAKTYYDo6?p=preview with the data you have..

Comment: @Ahmed look at the updated answer..which has plunkr and explaination too..why your code was not working..

Comment: It work fine, but does not work `ng-selected="year.id == 0"`, also instead `value="year.id"` I get `object:338`

Comment: @Ahmed `object:338` is the way of creating `ng-options`..don't worry about that.. And how come year value would be `0`,,could you provide me the non working plunkr

Comment: Okay, but does not work ng-select and string value in list

Comment: @Ahmed I don't understand what is your need..you are extending a question as m giving an answer.. :(

Answer (score 1):

**`ng-disabled`** is only meant to be use on `input` elements:

```
<INPUT
  ng-disabled="expression">
...
</INPUT>
```

[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code

`<option ng-repeat="year in data.dateList.year track by $index" ng-disabled="(year.id) < 2015">{{year.id}}</option>`

[see this code](http://plnkr.co/edit/UuQQ127MEg2lHSH13BUB?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean by Updated Question?