# Ng-disabled with condition from function?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following AngularJS code:

```
<option ng-repeat="year in data.dateList.year" value="{{year.id}}" ng-disabled="year.id < 2012" ng-selected="year.id == 0">
    {{year.value}}
</option>
```

The condition `year.id < 2012` works for `ng-disabled`. When I change this code to:

```
ng-disabled="year.id < getSelectedYear($index)"
```

It does not disable options.

The function `getSelectedYear` returns a value from first select list:

```
$scope.getSelectedYear = function (index){
    if($scope.selectedYear[index] != undefined){
        return $scope.selectedYear[index];
    }
}
```

If do `console.log($scope.selectedYear[index])` I get the value `2012`.

Why does the last case not work?

**About** `$scope.selectedYear`:

This variable is set by `ng-change="setSelectedYear(index, value)"`:

```
$scope.setSelectedYear = function (index, value){
     $scope.selectedYear[index] = value;
}
```

Where `index` is same that used in `setSelectedYear($index)`

Comment: May be it does not work for `option`?

Comment: So, the `$scope.selectedYear` have correlated indices with the `$scope.data.dateList.year` array? In other words, is the `$index` that you use correct for the `selectedYear` array?

Comment: I just compare two variables `year.id` and value from return of function thats contains type int

Comment: The `$scope.selectedYear` is not used in `ng-model` of select list. It is separeted variable

Comment: But you are using `$index` of one array (`data.dateList.year`) as the index to access the item of another (`selectedYear`). I'm asking if it was intentional. Are these two arrays aligned? Perhaps, add the sample data of each array

Comment: Please provide demo that includes enough data to replicate this. We have no idea what `selectedYear` contains. Also no need for a function to make the comparison

Comment: `$index` is by `ng-repeat`. Yes, `$scope.selectedYear` contains indexes same as `$scope.data.dateList.year`

Comment: I updated question about `selectedYear`

Comment: @Muhad does this question relates to http://stackoverflow.com/q/32570809/2435473 which asked for some sort of same question..

Comment: I have seen this question and had tried to build own case. I use current code on basement this question. But have problems

Comment: @Muhad where's the demo? You are the one asking for help but we have no way to inspect in browser or see the full code

Comment: Here's a demo that shows that it works (with assumptions I make about your data): http://plnkr.co/edit/lUhkDg96gVWEwBCcffcp?p=preview

Comment: It should be two relative select lists. You can add another select list with `ng-change="setSelectedYear($index, 2012)"` It will not work

Comment: @Muhad why can't you make the modification and fork the demo so we can see your problem live?

Comment: Sure, this is demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/cSN0EnkqHB1Yz4FGzUVz?p=preview

Comment: So, clearly, the demo you provided doesn't correspond to the question. `setSelectedYear` doesn't take `index` and `value`, and both use `[0]` as the index. I suggest you edit your question and make sure it is accurate and complete with respect to the demo.